# How to move images to new folder based on Metadata in Powershell

Tags: powershell, metadata

The type of photography I shoot demands two types of ISO sensitivities. 1.) ISO-200 2.) ISO-400. My current workflow changes depending on which ISO setting used. At the end of each day, I separate all my images into corresponding folders. This is one piece to several items I am attempting to automate.

Currently trying to write a script that will perform this task after images have already been imported to a "holding folder". This is what I have so far...

```
Function Get-FileMetaData
{

Param([string[]]$folder)
foreach($sFolder in $folder)
{
$a = 0
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder)

foreach ($File in $objFolder.items())
{
$FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT
for ($a ; $a -le 266; $a++)
{
if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
{
$hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) =
$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) }
$FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash
$hash.clear()
} #end if
} #end for
$a=0
$FileMetaData
} #end foreach $file
} #end foreach $sfolder
} #end Get-FileMetaData

$picdata = Get-FileMetaData -Folder 'D:\#Photos\To - Process\1' | select 
name, 'ISO speed', size, width, height
$picdata.'ISO Speed'
```

I have filtered the images by ISO speed but am unsure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated! I am very new to the scripting world.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Path" to the select statement; which contains the full path to the image file

```
select name, 'ISO speed', size, width, height, Path
```

You can then use the Copy-Item or Move-Item Cmdlets within an if statement to move or copy your image to a new location

As Get-FileMetaData returns multiple values, you will have to iterate through each of the results:

```
foreach ($pic in $picdata) {
    if ($pic.'ISO speed' -eq "ISO-200") {
        Copy-Item -Path $pic.Path -Destination "d:\photos\some_other_folder"
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Move-Item